# Python, Flask -- count page visit and write in database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

There is a small hello world Flask with visit statistics. I managed to count visits with redis, but I also have to add support storing date and number of visits in MySQL database. The current code is:
I was trying to access previously created database.
Currently I have no idea how to store such info in MySQL.

I was trying to access previously created database.
Currently I have no idea how to store such info in MySQL.

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host="redis")
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'passwd'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'hello'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'mysql'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    visits = redis.incr('counter')
    html = "<h3>Hello, world!</h3>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}" \
           "<br/>"
    return html.format(visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

How this can be solved? I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show what you treid with MySQL?

Comment: Show the code and explain how it didn't do what you wanted.

Comment: Updated code in original post. Unfortunately I don't know yet how to gather and store visits stats in db.

Comment: 1) Create a database scheme 2) use sql to update data whenever anyone visits your page. You probably need to read upon SQL for that (or use something like sqlalchemy).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Flask-SQLAlchemy: 
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

You will need to create the database with

```
from yourapplication import db
db.create_all()
```

I put in a check to create the counter if it hasn't been yet, but prob an unnecessary step.

Here is a working app with SQLite3.  If you really need MySQL, you can modify SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI as shown here:
[Switching from SQLite to MySQL with Flask SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766794/switching-from-sqlite-to-mysql-with-flask-sqlalchemy)
But it is, in my humble opinion, way overkill for this use.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Visit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    count = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    v = Visit.query.first()
    if not v:
        v = Visit()
        v.count += 1
        db.session.add(v)
    v.count +=1
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(counter=v.count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: this will increment everytime the page is refereshed or user visit this index page from same domain different page.