# Flask cannot connect to RDS MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I used flask-sqlalchemy with PostgreSQL.
Now, I switched to RDS MySQL,
so I changed SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
form

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://**************'
```

to

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{endpoint}:{port}?charset=utf8"
```

after this, I initialize app like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, logging, Response, redirect, flash, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.String(8),  primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)

    def __init__(self,params):
        self.id = params['id']
        self.name = params['name']
        self.email = params['email']

class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

@app.route('/get_user', methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    userid = request.args['id']
    user = User.query.get(userid)
    return user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But the app cannot connect to server.
(I confirmed username, password, endpoint, port, is correct and connected from mysql workbench)

I read this question.
[Switching from SQLite to MySQL with Flask SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766794/switching-from-sqlite-to-mysql-with-flask-sqlalchemy)
so I installed pymysql, but it didn't work.

When my app tried to connect db, this error message is shown.
it seems that psycopg2 is called although I'm using mysql.

Could you please give me some advise?

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "mysql+pymysql://mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}{endpoint}:{port}?charset"
```

Comment: Probably your connection string is missing '@' b/w password and endpoint..`Conn = "mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{endpoint}:{port}/{database}?charset=utf8"`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion
sorry, I missed '@' in my question, I corrected question

Comment: When u create the engine. Are you doing engine.connect() ? And can you put full stacktrace?

Comment: I use ```db = SQLAlchemy(app)```

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace in  your question

Comment: Thanks, I modified question.
If you need more information, please let me know

Comment: Yes i wanted to see the whole error log.

Comment: Thank you. 
In another module which i made, where was code like this..

```
import psycopg2 as pg
with pg.connect(self.db_url) as conn
```

I find this code is written with assumption using with postgreSQL.
So, i can fix this code.

Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: Great all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests to check your connection string with a debugger breakpoint, or just by printing.

```
print(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment,
printed URI is 
```mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{endpoint}:{port}/{database}?charset=utf8```

Answer (score 0):

it could be the uri format: **"dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database"**  in MySQL "mysql://username:password@localhost:####/mydatabase"
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#connection-uri-format